# ReceiverCallNotAllowedException when registering a BroadcastReceiver from within another BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

In the code below, I have a boot_completed BroadcastReceiver, where in **onReceive** I register another BroadcastReceiver to monitor calls changes. But it throws **ReceiverCallNotAllowedException**, as [according to document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ReceiverCallNotAllowedException) this happens when trying to register a BroadcastReceiver from within another BroadcastReceiver. So, what's your suggestion in this case, knowing that I don't want to launch an activity to register the call receiver.

> ReceiverCallNotAllowedException This exception is thrown from
> Context#registerReceiver and Context#bindService when these methods
> are being used from an BroadcastReceiver component. In this case, the
> component will no longer be active upon returning from receiving the
> Intent, so it is not valid to use asynchronous APIs.

**ServiceStarter.java** (The one receives boot_completed intent)

```
public class ServiceStarter extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent != null && intent.getAction() != null){
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction()) || Intent.ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
           
            registerCallReceiver(context);
        }
    }
}

public void registerCallReceiver(Context aCtx){
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
    
    // CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    CallReceiver receiver = new CallReceiver();
    aCtx.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <!--This part is inside the application-->
    <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I'm considering having a dummy service, that I start it from the ServiceStarter class, and use this dummy service to register the CallReceiver. What do you think.

**Edit 1:**

I created a dummy service to be started by ServiceStarter (A receiver gets called when the mobile boots), and in the dummy service I register the CallReceiver (BroadcastReceiver that monitors changes in calls status). But I ended up with the following exception:

> Service has leaked IntentReceiver in android

**ServiceStarter.java** (The one receives boot_completed intent)

```
public class ServiceStarter extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent != null && intent.getAction() != null){
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction()) || Intent.ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
           
            startDummyService(context);
        }
    }
}

public void startDummyService(Context aCtx){
    Intent intent = new Intent(aCtx, DummyService.class);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        aCtx.startForegroundService(intent);
    } else {
        aCtx.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

DummyService.java (Where I register CallReceiver broadcast)

```
public class DummyService extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
    CallReceiver receiver = new CallReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent aIntent, int aFlags, int aStartId){
    super.onStartCommand(aIntent, aFlags, aStartId);

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution to the **ReceiverCallNotAllowedException** that takes place when registering a BroadcastReceiver (CallReceiver) from another BroadcastReceiver (ServiceStarter).

This will cause the exception:

```
public void registerCallReceiver(Context aCtx){
   aCtx.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
}
```

This will not cause the exception:

```
public void registerCallReceiver(Context aCtx){
   aCtx.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, what's your suggestion in this case, knowing that I don't want to launch an activity to register the call receiver

Register for the broadcast in the manifest. That particular broadcast appears in [the list of implicit broadcasts for which you can register in the manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions).

Comment: The 2nd broadcast is for monitoring calls changes, which requires READ_PHONE_STATE permission, and it can't be implicit on latest Android version. I added more code above.

Comment: @AshrafAlshahawy: Then you will need to use a foreground service and have it call `registerReceiver()`. I think that your boot-time receiver can start that foreground service, though I forget if there are recent limitations on that.

Comment: I created a dummy service as a mediator between the ServiceStarter (Receiver) and the CallReceiver. And I ended up with "Service has leaked IntentReceiver in android". It expects me to unregister CallReceiver in onDestory of the dummy service. Which defeats the purpose, I want CallReceiver to be alive all the time to get notified when there's a change in the call status.

Comment: @AshrafAlshahawy: "I want CallReceiver to be alive all the time to get notified when there's a change in the call status" -- your foreground service needs to be running all the time.

Comment: @CommonWare I'm aware of that. But I can't accomplish this when mobile boots. I can't register CallReceiver from ServiceStarter (boot_completed) because both are BroadcastReceiver. And when I used a mediator (DummyService) between both of them, to register CallReceiver, I ended up with "Service has leaked IntentReceiver". I'm sure there's a solution out there for this situation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AshrafAlshahawy: "I'm aware of that" -- you did not implement a foreground service. You called `startForegroundService()`, which is a good starting point. However, the service then has a few seconds in which to call `startForeground()`, supplying a valid `Notification`. The code in your question does not show that. As a result, Android is treating your service as a regular service; there will be messages in Logcat to that effect. And, after a minute, Android will stop the service, at which point you should get that leak message.

Comment: @AshrafAlshahawy: You can read more about foreground services, such as the permission that you need to request in the manifest, in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services).

Comment: I finally by a miracle and a continuous search found a solution. Where I don't need to use a DummyService as a mediator between both BroadcastReceivers and to avoid the exception. It's pretty simple         aCtx.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter); The secret is using getApplicationContext(). Thank you so much for your help, really appreciated :)

Comment: could you help with this question? Thank you in advance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68343989/isgesturedetectionavailable-returns-false-on-android-10