# isGestureDetectionAvailable returns false on Android 10

Tags: android, sensors, fingerprint, android-biometric

**isGestureDetectionAvailable()** always returns false. I looked this issue up here on SO, and all those who faced the same problem in the past few years haven't received an answer or got it solved. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55878709/isgesturedetectionavailable-always-returns-false-on-android-28) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66777863/isgesturedetectionavailable-always-returns-false) And everywhere else. There will be a 50 points reward for the correct answer as a token of appreciation.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />


  <service
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name="helpers.FingerprintSVC"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagRequestFingerprintGestures"
        android:canRequestFingerprintGestures="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>
  </service>
```

FingerprintSVC

```
public class FingerprintSVC extends AccessibilityService {

private static final String TAG = "++++";

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent aIntent, int aFlags, int aStartId){
    super.onStartCommand(aIntent, aFlags, aStartId);

    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");

    if(!isAccessibilityServiceEnabled(this, this.getClass())){
        Toast toast= Toast.makeText(this, "Enable A.SVC", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
        toast.show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
}

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent");
}

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onInterrupt");
}

@Override
protected boolean onGesture(int gestureId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onGesture " + gestureId);
    return super.onGesture(gestureId);
}

@Override
protected boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onKeyEvent " + event.getKeyCode());
    return super.onKeyEvent(event);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDestroy" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}



@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();
    Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected");

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        FingerprintGestureController gestureController = getFingerprintGestureController();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Is available: " + gestureController.isGestureDetectionAvailable(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e(TAG, "Is available: " + gestureController.isGestureDetectionAvailable() );

        FingerprintGestureController.FingerprintGestureCallback callback = new
                FingerprintGestureController.FingerprintGestureCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGestureDetectionAvailabilityChanged(boolean available) {
                        super.onGestureDetectionAvailabilityChanged(available);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gesture available change to: " + available, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onGestureDetectionAvailabilityChanged " + available);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onGestureDetected(int gesture) {
                        super.onGestureDetected(gesture);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gesture: " + gesture, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onGestureDetected " + gesture);
                    }
                };

        gestureController.registerFingerprintGestureCallback(callback, new Handler());
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onUnbind " );
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}


public boolean isAccessibilityServiceEnabled(Context context, Class<?> accessibilityService) {
    ComponentName expectedComponentName = new ComponentName(context, accessibilityService);

    String enabledServicesSetting = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),  Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES);
    if (enabledServicesSetting == null)
        return false;

    TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter colonSplitter = new TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter(':');
    colonSplitter.setString(enabledServicesSetting);

    while (colonSplitter.hasNext()) {
        String componentNameString = colonSplitter.next();
        ComponentName enabledService = ComponentName.unflattenFromString(componentNameString);

        if (enabledService != null && enabledService.equals(expectedComponentName))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

}
```

build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxxx.xxxx"
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 30
}
```

I'm testing on Samsung M11 powered by Android 10. I don't have other devices to test on.

Comment: @CommonsWare Could you help with this? Thank you in advance